# System.InvalidOperationException: Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType Foo.Bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I am at my wit's end trying to resolve this.

I have a pretty significantly large MVC project using 4 Entity Framework models. The models are compiled into a separate assembly/class library type project.

Until a few days ago, everything was working fine. I was on leave for 2 days and someone tweaked the model and he's called severely sick.

When I came back today, I noticed that the app just won't start. It shows you the yellow screen of death with the following exception message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Mapping and metadata information could 
not be found for EntityType 'MyNamespace.MyClassName'
```

I checked out a few articles (http://blogs.infosupport.com/mapping-and-metadata-information-could-not-be-found-for-entitytype-schema-klant/, http://matheusandcode.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/mapping-and-metadata-information-could-not-be-found-for-entitytype/) and questions & answers from here and they all suggest that I cross-check for misspellings or missing properties between the POCO's and the model generated entities.

I have about 400+ entities. However, I checked the entity that it throws an exception while creating the entity set of, and there are absolutely no spelling mismatches. I've spent over 5 hours on checking this and I am tired and frustrated.

Anyone have any other leads as to the possible causes for this error?

I've cleaned, rebuilt, checked for spelling errors, missing properties, cross-checked parity between the conceptual and storage model using the Table Mappings window, the model browser and even SQL Server Management Studio, I've taken print-outs and marked every property on paper against the one in the POCO, I've rinsed and repeated a few times, but the error just won't go.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, EF 5, MVC 4 and the Entity Framework POCO Generator package.

Comment: Can you get on to the other developers machine and see if it works for them? Maybe they have uncommitted code or they updated the app to use their own DLL

Comment: When I came this morning, all the devs on the team reported this. I had a huge pile of email about this. And it occurs on my machine as well.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your setup, but I mean he could have changed something on his machine that breaks it for everyone else, but not for him. Just a thought though!

Comment: Source control? Have you tried reverting back to before the change was made?

Comment: @KyleC That's what I was planning to do if we didn't find a solution by end of day today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of the weary wayfarer.

In our case, we spotted the error to the following cause:

A developer had added an extra EDMX that did not use the EF POCO generator. In fact, the new model had no tables either. It just used a stored procedure.

He removed it and the error went away. We'll probably call the stored proc using vanilla ADO.NET instead of adding a new Entity Framework model for it.